# Can I use the LEFT (string) operator in ExecuteSQL()?

Tags: qgis, python, sql, ogr, string

In QGIS I can use the `LEFT` operator on a dataset like this:

```
LEFT( "Name2",3) ='031'
```

What is the syntax for using this expression with ogr in python? Isn't this the right syntax?

```
a=water.ExecuteSQL("select left('Name2',3)='031' from 'benlux_w_min' ")
'ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error`
```

A simple where clause works just fine

```
In [53]: a=water.ExecuteSQL("select * from 'benlux_w_min' where 'Name2'='0310027' ")

In [54]: a.GetFeatureCount()
Out[54]: 367
```

Comment: What kind of database are you working in? I don't think LEFT works in a FileGDB.

Comment: The source is map-info TAB-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that your SQL query should be something like this:

```
a=water.ExecuteSQL("SELECT LEFT(Name2,3) AS foo FROM benlux_w_min WHERE foo='031'")
```

Then, if the `LEFT` function doesn't work and the provider is OGR, you can try also with `SUBSTR`:

```
a=water.ExecuteSQL("SELECT SUBSTR(Name2,1,3) AS foo FROM benlux_w_min WHERE foo='031'")
```

following the [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_sql.html).

Comment: `LEFT` doesn't work in my case, querying a map info TAB file. The `SUBSTR` method does but not with the valid sql syntax you provided. I had to use `a=water.ExecuteSQL("SELECT * FROM benlux_w_min WHERE SUBSTR('Name2',1,3)='031'")` to get my query set.

Comment: I'm glad to know that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the query builder is something of a misnomer.  The interface you are looking for is `QgsExpression`.  `ExecuteSQL` will apply the sql expression through the layer providers SQL interface, such as for use with MSSQL or PostgreSQL.  I don't think TAB files support that.

`QgsExpression` is a simplified SQL-like interface for doing WHERE clauses on layers, and is well supported (though it doesn't support all SQL functions).

You can see a full example in the QGIS Python cookbook [here](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html).