# QGIS modeler - how to extract polygons by multiple arguments?

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-modeler

I'm using QGIS modeler to extract lines by not one, but multiple attributes. For example, I have a road network, and I want to extract only road with character values in field TYPE: value_one and value_two. How to do this using QGIS modeler?

[image]

Comment: Don't think it's possible to extract multiple values from QGIS Modeler. What about extracting for `value_one` by selecting the _contains_ operator, take the output and run another **Extract by attribute** and extract `value_two` by again, the _contains_ operator? The final result should yield you the layer with both attributes for the `Type` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible answer is to use multiple **Extract by attribute** functions.

Alternatively,  **Select by expression** and **Intersection** afterwards  could be used. 
In **Select by expression** function, it is possible to create such a expressions as:

```
"Variable_name" = 'Value_one' OR "Variable_name" = 'Value_two'
```

Answer (score 0):

use the or operator : "||" or the and if you want both : "&&"

For example 
"val1" || "val2"

Comment: Is this available in QGIS 2.8? I do not see this in 2.6.1.

Comment: I should think so yes. It is the same 'syntax' that you would use for styling your labels for example

Comment: Yes but are those operators selectable from the drop-down menu? In my version, you cannot enter the operator manually through the modeler.

Comment: Yes, true. IF you want more options I would use SQL with the GDAL/OGR tool cf http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83203/can-i-use-the-left-string-operator-in-executesql